# How do I combine file rename and upload php programs?

Tags: php

I am new to programming, and I need help with php.

I can use these two php program to upload files.(Individually they work well) 
I can't figure out how to combine them into one, 
so that one new program can VALIDATE, RENAME, and POST the two pictures.

I would also like a program to be included that will retrieve 
the Username and Email address from the logon session of the customer 
and verify that data into the the form.

I grately appreciate your help.Thanks

---

These are the PHP I am working with

```
 //This php validates and posts file to a folder "file_upload"

 <?php
 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
 $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 $extension = end($temp);

 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)
 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
//echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
//echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
//echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "file_upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  //echo "Stored in: " . "file_upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 }
}
 } else {
echo "Invalid file";
}
?> 


//These Php works fine together to rename and post files to separate folders 
//when the same user name is manually entered in the form


 <?php

 $destDir = 'rename_fotos/';   //can be any directory on your server, 

 $renamedFilename = $_POST['numbera']."-Foto1"; 
 //keep the same file extension if uploaded file has it
 $renamedFilename .= ($pos = strrpos($_FILES['file']['name'], '.')) === false ? '' :    substr($_FILES['file']['name'], $pos);

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .    $renamedFilename);

 echo "Foto File Uploaded <b>(code need upgrade!)</b>";
 ?> 

 <?php

 $destDir = 'rename_fotos2/';   //can be any directory on your server,` 

  $renamedFilename = $_POST['number']."-Foto2"; 
  //keep the same file extension if uploaded file has it
  $renamedFilename .= ($pos = strrpos($_FILES['file2']['name'], '.')) === false ? '' :      substr($_FILES['file2']['name'], $pos);

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"], $destDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .      $renamedFilename);

  echo "Foto File Uploaded <b>(code need upgrade!)</b>";
  ?>
```

Comment: Are you want to rename file name before upload the file ?

Comment: Yes (Suman Biswas),the 2 lower php does actually rename them, but I want to add the validation aspect of the upper php to the already renaming functionality of the lower ones, (to make one nice functional PHP that can Validate,Rename, and Post)

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with minus logic. Maybe looking at you can work better. What you wan't to do? It's like so....

```php
if (is_valid_upload_image($_FILES['file']) && is_valid_number($_POST['number'])) {
    $moved_file = move_to_definetely_local($_FILES['file']);
    rename_file_with_postname($moved_file, $POST['number']);
}
```

All `functions`/`methods` must be created but now, with the logic in head, you can work on each more efficiently.